# How do I remove/add css classes (and just general styling) in .gsp files (Grails)?

Tags: jquery, css, grails

I want to add/remove a class and other styling from a DOM element based on if the .gsp file gets to a specific part of the code, or passes an if-condition. How is this done?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. Using `class="${someModelVar.equals('someValue') ? 'add-this-class' : ''}"` is one example.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  and what does this have to do with grails and/or gsp, if you want to use jquery anyway?  what is the source of truth for the if-condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how you can do that...

```
if(condition)
{
  $(selector).addClass("theclassname");
  $(selectorAnother).addClass("theclassnameAnother");

}
```